# Tezos-client: unknown protocol after Ithaca upgrade

Tags: tezos-client, protocol, mainnet

I have installed tezos-client on MacOS via Home Brew. After Ithaca upgrade I am getting the following error message:

Fatal error: unknown protocol version.

I tried upgrading tezos-client by:
1)brew tap serokell/tezos-packaging https://github.com/serokell/tezos-packaging.git
2)brew tap serokell/tezos-packaging-stable https://github.com/serokell/tezos-packaging-stable.git

Without success. Any idea what else I can try?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using an old version of `tezos-client`, you need at least `v12.0` for Ithaca support.

You can check what version you are running by executing `tezos-client --version`, with the latest release (at the time of writing) it should show:

```
61fed540 (2022-03-31 10:53:22 +0200) (12.2)
```

Both `tezos-packaging` and `tezos-packaging-stable` are updated to the latest available Octez version (`v12.2`, as you can see above) and `brew tap` should be able to find that.

If you still have trouble I recommend checking [`brew`'s documentation](https://docs.brew.sh/Taps) or opening a [new issue in `tezos-packaging`](https://github.com/serokell/tezos-packaging/issues/new/choose).

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I have run both tezos-packaging and tezos-packaging-stable. When running "brew tap" I get the info that both packages are installed: 

homebrew/core
serokell/tezos-packaging
serokell/tezos-packaging-stable

Unfortunately the client still hasnt upgraded - after running tezos-client --version it shows it is still on 11.0

Any idea what can be done? Maybe uninstall tezos-client and reinstall it?

Comment: It sounds like you have used `brew tap` already, so you should be able to update.
I believe that the commands to run should be: `brew update` followed by another `brew install tezos-client`

Comment: it's probably also not the best idea to have both taps, to avoid confusion I suggest keeping only one of them (the `stable` one) and removing the cutting-edge one with `brew untap serokell/tezos-packaging`

Comment: Yes having both taps was probably the issue since client didnt know which one to consider. I was able to resolve it by simply uninstalling tezos-client and reinstalling it with the "stable" package. Now its back up and running. Thanks for your help! Will consider your proposed steps when next protocol upgrade is coming:)